# python 2.6.5, and getting the result of a call to a php app

Tags: php, python

i've got this snazzy python code:

```
import subprocess
value = subprocess.Popen(["php","./php/php_runner.php"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
```

the problem is, i have no idea how to check if the php_runner, well, ran. Currently, it has the following salient sections:

```
if (count($argv) != 4){
    die("four arguments are needed\n");
}
```

and

```
$returnValue =  call_to_another_php_class();
return $returnValue;
```

So what i want is this:

1. How do i get the return value, whatever it may be, using python?
2. You probably are going to tell me to use  "PIPE" in the answer, but the (to me, incomprehensible) python docs (http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) state:

   > Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. As the pipes are not being read in >the current process, the child process may block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up >the OS pipe buffer.
   >   So what do i use then, because while I don't really know what they're barking on about, i sit up and take note about notes in grey boxes. Pity they didn't spell out what i'm meant to do - but, well, what am i meant to do?
3. the "returnValue" that my php code returns, is *that* what python is going to pickup as the return value from the function? If not, how do i return that value?

cheers!

UPDATE

Thanks to the given answer, here's the changes i made:

1. edited `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini` (actually, this is just a change for ubuntu 10.04, and I changed the first line to begin with a ; instead of a #. That stopped an annoying "we don't like #" error that kept popping up)
2. in my php, I changed the code to read:

   ```
   if (count($argv) != 4){
       fwrite(STDERR, "four arguments are needed\n");
       exit(1); // A response code other than 0 is a failure
   }
   ```

   this puts my error value as an error. the die() command wasn't doing that for me.
3. changed the python to read:

   ```
   value = subprocess.Popen(["php","./php/php_runner.php"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,   
   stderr=subprocess.PIPE);
   print value.communicate();
   ```

   Yeah, realistically, i'd do an if on value.communicate()[1], becase that is where the errors are.
4. ```
   $returnValue =  call_to_another_php_class();
   if ($returnValue == 1){ //hah, php has a good return value as 1.
       //no problem
   } else {
       fwrite(STDERR,get_error_from_php_class());
       exit(1);
   }
   ```

booyah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the `Popen` constructor rather than the `call` functions, those notes about PIPE don't apply to you.

Use `.communicate()` as documented to wait for the program to finish and get the output.

Comment: thanks for this! I had looked at communicate earlier, but hadn't set it up with the PIPE stuff, so i thought it didn't work as i'd thought!